# Replace Label/span with an already made Label/span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, onload

I'm trying to replace the words in a span ("Grades")

```
<span class="vui-heading-1">Grades</span>
```

with a more definite name from another label (the title="Peer Tutor Training")

```
<a class="d2l-menuflyout-link-link" title="Peer Tutor Training" href="/d2l/home/419542">Peer Tutor Training</a>
```

Wanting the title to replace when the page loads, as I'm using this to replace a span wording in an iframe with the title within the same iframe.
Not entirely sure how to go about this. Thanks in advance!

*NOTE* Upon further inspection, it turns out that the  from the original page is not actually included into the iframe. Workaround method I'm requesting help with is an onload function to replace the "Grades" text in  to "Peer Tutoring Training" (or other text since this is only one example)

Comment: Could you show exactly what the result should be? Also, if the iframe is not coming from your own webserver, you won't be able to edit its content.

Comment: Might not even be possible to do, the <a class......> within the iframe is not even loaded, so the title="Peer Tutor Training"  is not even present to reference within the iframe.

Regardless the result should be like
<span class="vui-heading-1">Peer Tutor Training</span>

Comment: You could use AJAX-type calls to load the page, regular expressions to make your changes, then inject the content into your DOM.

Comment: Example code for this?

Comment: So is the `.vui-heading-1` and `.d2l-menuflyout-link-link` inside or outside the iframe? Please explain your html structure in more detail, e.g. where you want the code to run, where each element is, where the iframe is relative to the elements.

Comment: the .vui-heading-1 is within the iframe. The .d2l-menuflyout-link-link I originally thought was also in the iframe, however upon further inspection it is not actually in the iframe, or existent for the content I'm displaying. It's only on the original webpage. New change is to just replace <span>Grades</span> (the "Grades" text) with "sampleTextHere" with onload

Answer (score 0):

```
var $iframe = $('iframe#your-iframe'); // iframe that u wanna modify
$iframe.on('load',function(e) {
  // get the title value
  var title = $(this).find('a.d2l-menuflyout-link-link').attr('title'); 
  // get the span element
  var $span = $(this).find('span.vui-heading-1');
  // replace the text in the span
  $span.text(title);
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to change this coding to change the span text to a manual text? Like;
var $iframe = $('frame#your-iframe');
$iframe.on('load',function(e) {
var $span = $(this).find('span.vui-heading-1');
$span.text(Peer Tutor Training)

Comment: sure, use  $span.text('Peer Tutor Training');